# OMNIORB: uses Vmnet8 ip in IOR which is not reachable outside the server

Tags: corba, iiop, omniorb

I have installed a CORBA server on a machine that also runs VMWare-Player.
The VMWare player creates two virtual Network connections. The VMnet8 connection is used for VM network NAT mode.

Accidentially my Corba server picks this network connection as first not loopback interface and uses the ip of this inside its IOR and nameservice which means the IP is not accessible from clients.

Is there a way to set the default IP without setting a fixed endpoint in omniorb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation on the [endPoint* family of options](http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/omni41/omniORB/omniORB004.html#toc23). You can specify which interfaces servers will listen on and publish in IORs.

These options can be set on the command line, a config file, extra argument to `orb_init()`, or environment variable. More information on the configuration API can be found [here](http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/omni41/omniORB/omniORB004.html).

Comment: -ORBendPointPublish giop:tcp:127.0.0.1:2809 does the job